# GTM enhanced ecommerce : implement Add to Cart function

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, prestashop, google-tag-manager

I'm struggling from weeks now to implement the Add to Cart function with Google Tag Manager on my Prestashop website.

I do have transactions details and impressions pages, but I don't understand how to configure Add to Cart. Following Google instructions, here what I've done :
-For the tag, I just took the same instructions than in Google Documentation.
-The trigger: [trigger-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS2ol.png)

I guess another thing has to be enter instead of "addToCart" field. I tried to trigger the tag with a click event on my addtocart class button, but I just had the data of an event, I never had the "add" action in my data layer.

Where am I wrong ?

I'm working on the basic demo PrestaShop website.

Any help would be really useful !

Thanks

Comment: For further details, see the documentation: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#cart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call function on cart addition.

```
<script>
   function addToCart(product) {
   dataLayer.push({
     'event': 'addToCart',
     'ecommerce': {
       'currencyCode': 'EUR',
       'add': {                                // 'add' actionFieldObject measures.
         'products': [{                        //  adding a product to a shopping cart.
           'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',
           'id': '12345',
           'price': '15.25',
           'brand': 'Google',
           'category': 'Apparel',
           'variant': 'Gray',
           'quantity': 1
          }]
       }
     }
   });
   }
   </script>
```

After that you should fix your firing rule:
Event name — addToCart,
remove all other conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not a developer so I have two questions :
-I guess I have to place this script in my header for all pages, but isn't GTM goal to avoid multiple scripts ?
-I guess I have to replace things in the product part like :
'price':'$product->show_price' . But do you know how I link this function when the cart addition is done in PrestaShop?

Comment: 1) You should call this function on «Add to cart» button click.
You want be abble to complete your task without javascripts implementations. 
2) It's just an example, you should replace values for your product values.
Unfortunatelly, I'm not familiar with PrestaShop.